# Integral Large not working with packages

Tags: fontsize, integral

I have been trying to increase the size of the integral to be sizable relative to the rest of the function inside the integral with no luck, I believe it is due to the black background. Is there a way around this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, graphicx, amsmath,  graphicx, fullpage, modern, mathtools, bigints}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}

\color{red} \center 

\fontsize{40}{20} $$ \text{Intuitive Approach to}$$
$$\text{Trigonometric Integration}$$

\bf\scalebox{1}{$\displaystyle{\bigints} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 25}}{x}dx$}

\end{document}
```

Currently the integral gets ever so slightly larger, but nothing substantial. I would like it to be relative to the function inside. I have tried these packages as well, mtpro2, and relsize but with no luck, getting any bigger. Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of inaccuracies in your code. For example, it should be `\fontsize{20}{40}`, not `\fontsize{40}{20}`, and `\displaystyle` is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an an argument. I'd also say that you're seriously abusing the `$$ ... $$` mechanism to center-set *text material*.

Anyway, here's how I'd go about streamlining your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
%\color{white}
\color{red} 
\centering
\parbox{4in}{\centering\fontsize{20}{35}\selectfont 
   Intuitive Approach to Trigonometric Integration
   \par\bigskip
   $\displaystyle\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 25}}{x}\,dx$
   }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I am new to Latex so thank you for correcting my inaccuracies!!